# Use fsockopen with proxy to detect valid mails

Tags: php, proxy, fsockopen

I'm trying to create a mail testing function, to avoid bounces when mailing.

Since I have to check a lot of email addresses, I need to use proxy in order to avoid google ban server IP.

I'm not sure if I can do this, but is it  possible to do this with proxies?

```
$toemail = 'mail to test';
$fromemail = 'mail from';

$connect = @fsockopen($mx_ip, 25); 

// $mx_ip = aspmx2.googlemail.com

if($connect){ 
    if(preg_match("/^220/i", $out = fgets($connect, 1024))){
        fputs ($connect , "HELO $mx_ip\r\n"); 
        $out = fgets ($connect, 1024);
        $details .= $out."\n";

        fputs ($connect , "MAIL FROM: <$fromemail>\r\n"); 
        $from = fgets ($connect, 1024); 
        $details .= $from."\n";

        fputs ($connect , "RCPT TO: <$toemail>\r\n"); 
        $to = fgets ($connect, 1024);
        $details .= $to."\n";

        fputs ($connect , "QUIT"); 
        fclose($connect);

        if(!preg_match("/^250/i", $from) || !preg_match("/^250/i", $to)){
            $result = "invalid"; 
        }
        else{
            $result = "valid";
        }
    } 
}
else{
    $result = "invalid";
    $details .= "Could not connect to server";
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned that Google [or whichever service ] will ban due to over use your main server, then the same service could ban the Proxy as well. So I don't think using proxy server will resolve your issue.

I think you should consider a paid service, which will not ban you in the first place.

Comment: If a paid service is being banned [because /despite] it is using proxies , it will not be your headache .. they will start using a different proxy.

Comment: and i'm thinking of doing the same